# How to sum a substring reference

Tags: r, plyr

I'm attempting to select the correct column to sum the total of a from within a data frame column using ddply:

```
df2 <- ddply(df1,'col1', summarise, total = sum(substr(variable,1,3)))
```

It appears not to be working because you can't sum a character, but I am trying to pass the reference to the column, not sum the literal result of the substring. Is there a way to get around this?

Example Data & Desired output:

variable = "Aug 2017"

`col1 Jun Jul Aug
1     A   1   2   3
2     A   1   2   3
3     A   1   2   3
4     A   1   2   3
5     A   1   2   3
6     B   2   3   4
7     B   2   3   4
8     B   2   3   4
9     C   3   4   5
10    C   3   4   5`


`Desired Output:
1     A   15

2     B   12
3     C   10`

Comment: Can you provide some sample data, as well as an example of what outcome you are expecting?

Comment: Just added, sorry for the slow reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with `dplyr` instead of `plyr`.

```
# create data
df1 <- data.frame(
    col1 = c(rep('A', 5), rep('B', 3), rep('C', 2)),
    Jun = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
    Jul = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4),
    Aug = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5))

variable = 'Aug 2017'

# load dplyr library
library(dplyr)
# summarize each column that matches some string
df1 %>%
  select(col1, matches(substr(variable, 1, 3))) %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  summarize_each(funs = 'sum')
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    col1   Aug
  <fctr> <dbl>
1      A    15
2      B    12
3      C    10
```

I also highly recommend reading about nonstandard and standard evaluation, here:
http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html